# Manipulate Thread Implementation in JVM

Tags: java, concurrency, multicore, concurrent-programming, java.util.concurrent

Recently, I've been working on the deployment of concurrent objects onto multicore. In a sample, I use [`BlockingQueue.take()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) method whose specification mentions that it is *blocking*. It means that the method does not release the enclosing thread's resources such that it can be re-used for other concurrent tasks. This is useful since the total number of live threads in a JVM instance is limited and if the application would need thousands of live threads, then it is vital to be able to re-use suspended threads. On the other hand, JVM uses a 1:1 mapping from application-level threads to OS-level threads in Java; i.e. each Java Thread instance becomes an underlying OS-level thread.

The current solution is based on `java.util.concurrency` in Java 1.5+. Still, we need worker threads that are such scalable to a large number. Now, I am interested to find the following answers:

- Is there any way to replace the implementation of `java.lang.Thread` in JVM such that I can plug my own Thread implementation?
- Is this only possible through tweaking C++ sections of the thread implementation in JVM and recompiling it?
- Is there any library to provide a way to replace the classical thread in Java?
- Again, in the same line, is there a library or a way to guide how *some* threads in Java can be mapped to *only one* thread in the OS-level?

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887130/java-implementation-of-a-jvm) discussing different implementations of JVM and I am not sure if they could help.

Thanks for your comments and ideas in advance.

Comment: I have one question: what _are_ you trying to do, in the big picture? Maybe that will help with finding a good answer.

Comment: if BlockingQueue.take() or blocking in general is your concern, you can rewrite that part of the code to use non-blocking using Condition (also in java.util.concurrent), peek if there's an object, if there's not an object, you can `await`. Whenever an object is introduced into the queue, then you can ´signal´ any _awaiting_ thread... this might not be as simple as it sounds, then again, it would be simpler than writing code for your own threads

Comment: @chris-jester-young In the big picture, each object uses an internal `ExecutorService` along with a repository of asynchronous messages stored in the object. The ES service constantly `take()`s the next message from the repo and tries to run it. The problem is that we want to make the object use a **single** thread of execution, so when the thread for `take()` is not released then we face this problem to have another separate thread for the actual execution of the message. Please let me know if more elaboration is needed.

Comment: @cahuistle Thanks for your comment. I will look into your suggestion. I am not sure if `await()` releases the enclosing thread resources. By blocking, it is meant that we need to completely detach the thread to be re-used for another execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating thousands of threads, you're doing it wrong.

Instead, consider using the Executor framework. (Start with the `Executors` and `ThreadPoolExecutor` classes.) They allow you to queue thousands of tasks while having a sane number of threads handling them.

I guess this approach is what you meant by "library to replace the classical threads". I highly recommend you look into executors.

One caveat: Executors, by default, use non-daemon threads. Therefore, you must shut down your executor when you're done with it. You can do this at program exit, if there is a normal way to exit your program that doesn't simply involve waiting for all threads to finish. :-)

Comment: Actually, the current solution is based on `java.util.concurrency` in Java 1.5+. Still, we need worker threads  that are such scalable to a large number. Thanks for your comment to remind this.

Comment: @Behrooz: If you need to handle C10k or something like that, threads may not be the best way to do it. Instead, you can use something like asynchronous I/O (which will debut with Java 7's NIO.2 library).